# useFetch of Nuxt 3 sends same request during refresh instead of updating URL

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I try to do a simple thing: At route change, refetch data.

Here is my link:

```html
<li v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id" class="mb-1">
  <NuxtLink :to="{ query: { cat: category.slug } }">
    {{category.title}}
  </NuxtLink>
</li>
```

And my request:

```html
<script setup>
const route = useRoute()

const { data:categories } = await useFetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/category/', {
  key: route.fullPath, 
  initialCache: false
})
const { data:tasks, refresh } = await useFetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/?cat=${route.query.cat}`, {
  key: `tasks:${route.query.cat}`, 
  initialCache: false
})

watch(() => route.query.cat, () => refresh())

</script>
```

So, at click, url is well changed:

```
http://localhost:3000/tasks?cat=category1
http://localhost:3000/tasks?cat=category3
http://localhost:3000/tasks?cat=category2
```

But requests are the same (from Django DRF backend):

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/?cat=category1
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/?cat=category1
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/?cat=category1
```

It seems that it keeps the first category, even with `initialCache: false`

Comment: Did you try `() => \`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/?cat=${route.query.cat}\`` as URL for `useFetch`?

Comment: It's working! ```const { data: tasks, refresh } = await useFetch(() => `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/?cat=${cat.value}`) ```
What is behind this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the URL should not be provided as string

```js
const { data:tasks, refresh } = await useFetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/?cat=${route.query.cat}`, {
  key: `tasks:${route.query.cat}`, 
  initialCache: false
})
```

but as a function returning a string:

```js
const { data:tasks, refresh } = await useFetch(() => `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/?cat=${route.query.cat}`, {
  key: `tasks:${route.query.cat}`, 
  initialCache: false
})
```

Answer (score 5):

`useFetch` is "freezing" the API URL, the changes you make to the string directly will not be reflected. If you want to add parameters to your API URL, as an alternative to using a function, you can use the `query` option of `useFetch`. This option is reactive, that is when the ref with your route is changing, the query will reflect this update.

For your case, this will work:

```ts
const cat = ref('your_value')

const { data:tasks, refresh } = await useFetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks', {
  query: { cat }
})
```

This results in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks?cat=your_value`

You don't need to mess with the key option, as the key will be auto generated, and you can also leave the cache alone.

The query option is not well documented yet, as discussed in this [nuxt issue](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/8708). I've created a pull request on nuxt/framework to have it reflected in the documentation. Please see a full explanation below:

Using the `query` option, you can add search parameters to your query. This option is extended from [unjs/ohmyfetch](https://github.com/unjs/ohmyfetch) and is using [ufo](https://github.com/unjs/ufo) to create the URL. Objects are automatically stringified.

```ts
const param1 = ref('value1')
const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains',{
    query: { param1, param2: 'value2' }
})
```

This results in `https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains?param1=value1&param2=value2`

Comment: In the docs **params**: Alias for query. But it doesn't refresh data.

Answer (score -1):

This solution works if you have multiple query params.

For example, working with [Vuetify Server Side Data Tables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/server-side-tables/)

```js
const query = reactive({
  limit: 1,
  page: 1,
});


const {
  data: integrationsConnections,
  refresh,
} = await useFetch("GET", "/resources", { query });


const handleDataChange = (params) => {
  query.page = params.page;
  query.limit = params.itemsPerPage;

  refresh();
};
```

Comment: This does not work for me. For some reason query/params are NOT reactive. useFetch will not change the params for the request. Could you help? See my question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285170/nuxt-3-server-side-pagination-with-usefetch