# Nuxt 3 server-side pagination with useFetch

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, nuxtjs3

I'm using Quasar UI and Nuxt 3. I have an existing API that I can access. Have nuxt2 project that works fine with Axios but trying to now use useFetch as per Nuxt3 docs.

Quasar's qTable has pagination object. I want to refetch data when table changes by updating the pagination params sent to server, i.e. server-side pagination.

I'm struggling to undersand where I've gone wrong in the following code.

```
 const pagination = ref({
  sortBy: "",
  descending: true,
  page: 1,
  rowsPerPage: 20,
  rowsNumber: 100,

    });
    
    //Get Data
    const { data, error, pending, refresh } = await useAPIFetch<CustomResponse>(uri,
  {
    method: "GET",
    params: {
      search: search,
      list: false,
      sort: pagination.value.sortBy,
      sortOrder: pagination.value.descending ? "desc" : "asc",
      size: pagination.value.rowsPerPage,
      page: pagination.value.page,
    },
    watch: [search],
  }
);

//Set posts and meta data
const posts = data.value?.data;
const meta = data.value?.meta;
pagination.value.rowsNumber = meta.total;

//Sets params  and runs when the table is sorted, filtered or paginated.
const handleRequest = (props) => {
const { page, rowsPerPage, sortBy, descending } = props.pagination
  pagination.value.sortBy = sortBy;
  pagination.value.descending = descending;
  pagination.value.page = page;
  pagination.value.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
  search.value = filter;
  console.log(pagination.value);
  refresh();
};
```

I would expect the refresh() method called would send a new request with the updated pagination. But it doesn't, it only seems to see the initial pagination.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had misunderstood the reactivity of Vue3. The params must be a reactive object, not .value of the ref.

Revised code here:

```
//Set initial pagination state
const pagination = ref<Pagination>({
  sortBy: "",
  descending: true,
  page: 1,
  rowsPerPage: 20,
  rowsNumber: 0,
});

//Set API request params
const requestParams = computed(() => {
  return {
    sort: pagination.value.sortBy,
    size: pagination.value.rowsPerPage,
    page: pagination.value.page,
    list: list.value,
    sortOrder: pagination.value.descending ? "desc" : "asc",
    search: search.value,
  };
});

//Fetch Data
const { data, error, pending, refresh } = await useFetch<CustomResponse>(
  apiRoute,
  {
    baseURL: runTimeConfig.public.apiBaseURL,
    method: "GET",
    query: requestParams,
  }
);

//Update pagination state with server response data.
pagination.value.page = data?.value?.meta ? data.value.meta.page : 1;
pagination.value.rowsPerPage = data?.value?.meta
  ? data.value.meta.rowsPerPage
  : 20;
pagination.value.sortBy = data?.value?.meta ? data.value.meta.sortBy : "id";
pagination.value.descending = data?.value?.meta
  ? data.value.meta.descending
  : true;
pagination.value.rowsNumber = data?.value?.meta ? data.value.meta.total : 0;

//Handle pagination state change
const handleRequest = (paginationProps: PaginationProps) => {
  const { page, rowsPerPage, sortBy, descending } = paginationProps.pagination;
  pagination.value.page = page;
  pagination.value.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
  pagination.value.sortBy = sortBy;
  pagination.value.descending = descending;
  pagination.value.rowsNumber = data?.value?.meta ? data.value.meta.total : 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer with code:

```
//Fetch data from API
const { data, error, pending, refresh } = await useFetch<CustomResponse>(
  apiRoute,
  {
    baseURL: runTimeConfig.public.apiBaseURL,
    method: "GET",
    query: requestParams,
  }
);

watch(data, () => {
  updatePagination();
  if (error.value) {
    handleError(error.value);
  }
});

//Update pagination state with server response data.
const updatePagination = async () => {
  const meta = data?.value?.meta;
  pagination.value.page = meta ? meta.current_page : 1;
  pagination.value.rowsPerPage = meta ? meta.per_page : 20;
  pagination.value.rowsNumber = meta ? meta.total : 0;
};

//Handle new request from pagination or search.
const handleRequest = async (paginationProps: PaginationProps) => {
  const { page, rowsPerPage, sortBy, descending } = paginationProps.pagination;
  pagination.value.page = page;
  pagination.value.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
  pagination.value.sortBy = sortBy;
  pagination.value.descending = descending;
};
```